# How to reset values and restart program in C

Tags: default, reset, restart

I was wondering on if it was possible to reset all values in a program so that when i call main() to restart my program all the ints and arrays are back to their default values.

Thanks everybody!

P.S. I declared all my values above my main().

Comment: you shouldn't be calling main yourself

Comment: Would it be a good idea to declare your values inside `main()`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to do it manually since you are using global variables.